# Why spark csv filters out empty rows?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When reading CSV file with `spark.read.csv('path to file')`. It filters out all empty rows.

1. What is the reason it does that?
2. Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1):

Spark internally filters empty lines when parsing CSV strings into `InternalRow`. You can see that in the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0494dc90af48ce7da0625485a4dc6917a244d580/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/csv/CSVUtils.scala#L31):

```scala
/**
   * Filter ignorable rows for CSV dataset (lines empty and starting with `comment`).
   * This is currently being used in CSV schema inference.
   */
  def filterCommentAndEmpty(lines: Dataset[String], options: CSVOptions): Dataset[String]
```

Not sure why you're asking for a way to change this, an empty line simply represents nothing as it contains no data, so why would you like to keep it and how should it be parsed in such a case? Not to be confused with malformed (corrupted) records which you can handle using [`mode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html#data-source-option) in CSV data source options.

---

##### EDIT

If you really need to keep empty lines in the dataframe then you can read it as text instead of CSV:

```scala
val df = spark.read.text("path")
```

The dataframe will have only one column `value`, you'll have to parse it yourself into multiple columns (using `split` function for example, or [from_csv](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#from_csv) if you have Spark 3+) but it keeps the empty lines.

Comment: when spark filter empty rows I can't know that my file is damaged and has corrupted rows, when using `.option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")` that what I need to check.

Comment: When spark filters these rows, I can't know they exist in the file... so I don't understand your answer.

Comment: reading with text and parsing will require many error handling, etc. looking at the code it is very easy to add configuration for my case, and as such spark will be able to reproduce the behavior of excel, sqlldr, Postgres loader etc.